# Add and move components at runtime Java

Tags: java, swing, button, label

I want to add, move and set properties (font and rotation) of components at **runtime**.

In other words, I need to add a button, a label, drag them using mouse and set a component's properties at runtime. Is there any example Java swing for or similar to this?

**This is my code**  **:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;






public class prova extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener,MouseListener{




    //*************** INIZIALIZZAZIONE VARIABILI  ***************************  



Checkbox CB=new Checkbox("Label",true);
Button BP=new Button("BUTTON_1");
Button B=new Button("OK");
JComboBox combo1=new JComboBox();
JMenuBar menuBar;
int app=0;
static int anglePeso=0;
static int angleTara=0;
ImageIcon ic;
Border border = LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder();
static int pesoX=184;
static int pesoY=91;
static boolean taraVisible=false;
static boolean pesoVisible=false;
static boolean logo1Visible=false;
static boolean BarCodeVisible=false;  
static String font="";
static String rot="";
Label societa=new Label ("Società");
Label importo=new Label ("Importo");
Label nome=new Label("Nome Prodotto");
static int logo1X=250;
static int logo1Y=90;
static Component C;
static int label1X=183;
static int label1Y=91;
static int taraX=100; 
//TextField TF=new TextField(10);
static Panel P=new Panel();
//List TA=new List();
boolean b1=false;
int c1=0;int c2=0;
static JLabel logo2=new JLabel("Logo2");
  static int aa=0;


  static int importoX=0;
  static int importoY=0;


 public static boolean isBarCodeVisible() {
        return BarCodeVisible;
    }

    public static void setBarCodeVisible(boolean BarCodeVisible) {
        prova.BarCodeVisible = BarCodeVisible;
    }

    public static Component getC() {
        return C;
    }

    public static void setC(Component C) {
        prova.C = C;
    }




    public static int getAnglePeso() {
        return anglePeso;
    }

    public static void setAnglePeso(int anglePeso) {
        prova.anglePeso = anglePeso;
    }






 static ImageIcon immLogo1;

    public JLabel getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(JLabel barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public static ImageIcon getImmLogo1() {
        return immLogo1;
    }

    public static void setImmLogo1(ImageIcon immLogo1) {
        prova.immLogo1 = immLogo1;
    }





    public static void setFont(String font) {
        prova.font = font;
    }

    public static String getRot() {
        return rot;
    }

    public static void setRot(String rot) {
        prova.rot = rot;
    }

    public static boolean isPesoVisible() {
        return pesoVisible;
    }

    public static void setPesoVisible(boolean pesoVisible) {
        prova.pesoVisible = pesoVisible;
    }

    public static boolean isTaraVisible() {
        return taraVisible;
    }

    public static void setTaraVisible(boolean taraVisible) {
        prova.taraVisible = taraVisible;
    }



static JLabel label1=new JLabel("Peso"){



protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
AffineTransform aT = g2.getTransform();
Shape oldshape = g2.getClip();
double x = getWidth()/2.0;
double y = getHeight()/2.0;
aT.rotate(Math.toRadians(anglePeso), x, y);
// g2.transform(aT);
g2.setTransform(aT);
g2.setClip(oldshape);
super.paintComponent(g);
}
};
Label data=new Label("Data");
static JLabel tara=new JLabel("Tara"){

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
AffineTransform aT = g2.getTransform();
Shape oldshape = g2.getClip();
double x = getWidth()/2.0;
double y = getHeight()/2.0;
aT.rotate(Math.toRadians(angleTara), x, y);
// g2.transform(aT);
g2.setTransform(aT);
g2.setClip(oldshape);
super.paintComponent(g);
}
};
static JLabel logo1=new JLabel("Logo1");



    public static JLabel getTara() {
        return tara;
    }

    public static void setTara(JLabel tara) {
        prova.tara = tara;
    }
static JLabel barcode=new JLabel ("Bar Code");/*{



protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
AffineTransform aT = g2.getTransform();
Shape oldshape = g2.getClip();
double x = getWidth()/2.0;
double y = getHeight()/2.0;
aT.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x, y);
// g2.transform(aT);
g2.setTransform(aT);
g2.setClip(oldshape);
super.paintComponent(g);
}
};
*/



    public static JLabel getLogo1() {
        return logo1;
    }

    public static void setLogo1(JLabel logo1) {
        prova.logo1 = logo1;
    }

    public static boolean isLogo1Visible() {
        return logo1Visible;
    }

    public static void setLogo1Visible(boolean logo1Visible) {
        prova.logo1Visible = logo1Visible;
    }

    public static int getLogo1X() {
        return logo1X;
    }

    public static void setLogo1X(int logo1X) {
        prova.logo1X = logo1X;
    }

    public static int getLogo1Y() {
        return logo1Y;
    }

    public static void setLogo1Y(int logo1Y) {
        prova.logo1Y = logo1Y;
    }

    public static int getTaraX() {
        return taraX;
    }

    public static void setTaraX(int taraX) {
        prova.taraX = taraX;
    }

    public static int getTaraY() {
        return taraY;
    }

    public static void setTaraY(int taraY) {
        prova.taraY = taraY;
    }
static int taraY=90;

    public int getLabel1X() {
        return label1X;
    }

    public void setLabel1X(int label1X) {
        this.label1X = label1X;
    }

    public int getLabel1Y() {
        return label1Y;
    }

    public void setLabel1Y(int label1Y) {
        this.label1Y = label1Y;
    }


public prova(){



}


public prova(String titlu)
{
super(titlu);
}
void init(int b,int h, String [] par) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
setLayout(null);

System.out.println("****************COORINATE PESO: "+label1X+" "+label1Y);

menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
  JMenu filemenu = new JMenu("File");
  filemenu.add(new JSeparator());
  JMenu editmenu = new JMenu("Edit");
  editmenu.add(new JSeparator());
  JMenuItem fileItem1 = new JMenuItem("New");
  JMenuItem fileItem2 = new JMenuItem("Open");
  JMenuItem fileItem3 = new JMenuItem("Close");
  fileItem3.add(new JSeparator());
  JMenuItem fileItem4 = new JMenuItem("Save");
  JMenuItem editItem1 = new JMenuItem("Cut");
  JMenuItem editItem2 = new JMenuItem("Copy");
  editItem2.add(new JSeparator());
  JMenuItem editItem3 = new JMenuItem("Paste");
  JMenuItem editItem4 = new JMenuItem("Insert");
  filemenu.add(fileItem1);
  filemenu.add(fileItem2);
  filemenu.add(fileItem3);
  filemenu.add(fileItem4);
  editmenu.add(editItem1);
  editmenu.add(editItem2);
  editmenu.add(editItem3);
  editmenu.add(editItem4);
  menubar.add(filemenu);
  menubar.add(editmenu);
  setJMenuBar(menubar);
  //setSize(400,400);
  //setVisible(true);

fileItem4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Cliccato Save ");
                 punti();
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
InserimentoDB is=new InserimentoDB();



Image im=is.getImage("select immagine from etichette where id= 75");
ic=new ImageIcon(im);


P.setBackground(Color.red);


String[] mm=new String [4];

mm[0]="0";
mm[1]="90";
mm[2]="180";
mm[3]="270";


        combo1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(mm) {});

   combo1.addMouseMotionListener(this);
combo1.addMouseListener(this);  

combo1.setLocation(200,100);combo1.setSize(80,40);
//add(combo1);

        System.out.println("LabelX: "+label1X);
        System.out.println("LabelY: "+label1Y);

     // label1.getParent().repaint();



/*
l.addMouseMotionListener(this);
l.addMouseListener(this);

l1.addMouseMotionListener(this);
l1.addMouseListener(this);

l2.addMouseMotionListener(this);
l2.addMouseListener(this);

l3.addMouseMotionListener(this);
l3.addMouseListener(this);

*/
for (int i=0; i<par.length; i++){

    System.out.println("Parametri ricevuti "+par[i]);





}


//TA.addMouseMotionListener(this);
//TA.addMouseListener(this);
B.addMouseMotionListener(this);
B.addMouseListener(this);
P.addMouseMotionListener(this);
P.addMouseListener(this);
CB.addMouseMotionListener(this);
CB.addMouseListener(this);

if (par[6].equalsIgnoreCase("logo1")){

    if(logo1Visible){


        System.out.println("*******LOGO1: "+immLogo1);
       // logo1.setIcon(immLogo1);
    logo1.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    logo1.addMouseListener(this);

  //  System.out.println("Imm Logo1: "+immLogo1.getDescription());

    logo1.setIcon(ic);


    logo1.setLocation(logo1X,logo1Y);



    //label1.setLocation(pesoX,pesoY);
    logo1.setSize(384,160);
    add(logo1);

    }

}

if (par[0].equalsIgnoreCase("peso")){

    if(pesoVisible){

       // label1.setBorder(border);
    label1.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    label1.addMouseListener(this);

    label1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    //label1.setFont(font);

    label1.setLocation(label1X,label1Y);

    //label1.setLocation(pesoX,pesoY);
    label1.setSize(100,20);
   // label1.setIcon(immLogo1);
    add(getContent());
    //add(getCombo());

    label1.setName("peso");

    add(label1);
    repaint();

    }

}

if (par[1].equalsIgnoreCase("tara")){

    if(taraVisible){

    tara.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    tara.addMouseListener(this);
    //tara.setLocation(49,130);

     tara.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    tara.setLocation(taraX,taraY);
    tara.setSize(100,20);
    tara.setName("tara");
    add(tara);
    repaint();
    }
}

if (par[2].equalsIgnoreCase("importo")){

    importo.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    importo.addMouseListener(this);
    importo.setLocation(44,91);importo.setSize(100,20);
    importo.setName("IMPORTO");

    add(importo);
}

if (par[3].equalsIgnoreCase("bar code")){

    if(BarCodeVisible){

    barcode.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    barcode.addMouseListener(this);


    ImageIcon icon =  new ImageIcon("/home/max/Downloads/ce.jpg");
    barcode.setIcon(icon);




    barcode.setLocation(81,223);barcode.setSize(284,177);

    add(barcode);
    }
}

if (par[4].equalsIgnoreCase("data")){

    data.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    data.addMouseListener(this);
   // data.setLocation(184,177);
    data.setSize(100,20);
    data.setName("data");
    add(data);
}

if (par[5].equalsIgnoreCase("nome prodotto")){

    nome.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    nome.addMouseListener(this);
    nome.setLocation(43,186);nome.setSize(100,20);

    add(nome);
}


ImageIcon icon1 =  new ImageIcon("/home/max/Downloads/ce.jpg");
    logo2.setIcon(icon1);
    logo2.setLocation(100, 50);
    add(logo2);

//add(B);***********************

B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

                System.out.println("Cliccato");

                punti();
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });


/*data.addMouseMotionListener(this);
data.addMouseListener(this);

societa.addMouseMotionListener(this);
societa.addMouseListener(this);

barcode.addMouseMotionListener(this);
barcode.addMouseListener(this);

TA.setLocation(50,50);
TA.setSize(100,100);TA.add("List");

CB.setLocation(120,370);CB.setSize(100,20);

data.setLocation(184,177);data.setSize(100,20);
societa.setLocation(112,41);societa.setSize(100,20);

barcode.setLocation(44,178);barcode.setSize(100,20);*/

B.setLocation(100,150);B.setSize(80,40);

P.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
P.setLocation(100,200);P.setSize(150,150);
P.setBackground(Color.yellow);
P.add(BP,BorderLayout.NORTH);
//P.add(TF,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//add(TA);add(B);add(P);add(CB);
//add(l);add(l1);add(l2);add(l3);add(label);

//add(label);
//add(data);add(societa);add(tara);add(barcode);

setLocation(500,500);
setSize(b*10,h*10);
setVisible(true);

//show();
}
//mouseDragged
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
Component C=e.getComponent();
if(b1==false){b1=true;Point p=new
Point(e.getPoint());c1=p.x;c2=p.y;}
Point z=new Point(e.getPoint());
Point q=new Point(C.getLocation());
C.setBounds(q.x+(z.x-c1),q.y+(z.y-c2),C.getSize().
width,C.getSize().height);
repaint();
}
//mouseReleased
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
b1=false;
System.out.println("Mouse Rilascaito");
Component C=e.getComponent();
System.out.println("*******++++++++++**********+++++++++Coordinate"+ C);
System.out.println("NOme: "+C.getName());

if(C.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("importo")){

    importo.setLocation(C.getX(), C.getY());

    importoX=C.getX();
    importoY=C.getY();

}

if(C.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("data")){

    data.setLocation(C.getX(), C.getY());

}


if(C.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("peso")){

    label1X=C.getX();
    label1Y=C.getY();

}
C.getX();
C.getY();

//Attenzione qui sotto da controllare!!!!!!!

//pesoX=e.getX();
//pesoY=e.getY();

repaint();
}
//mouseEntered
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
{
Cursor c1=new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
setCursor(c1);
}
//mouseExited
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
{
Cursor c2=new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
setCursor(c2);
}
//mouseClicked
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{


    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
         Component C=e.getComponent();

         System.out.println("*****************+NOme componente: "+C.getName());


         System.out.println("Coordinate: "+C.getLocation());

         System.out.println("XXX: "+C.getX());
         System.out.println("YYY: "+C.getY());
       // Configurazione cc=new Configurazione();
       // cc.setComponente(C.getName());

       // cc.main();

         Configurazione cf=new Configurazione();

        // cf.setC(C);

         cf.main();



         //RotLabel rot=new RotLabel();

         //rot.main();

        System.out.println("\n\nRotazione: "+rot);
        System.out.println("Font: "+font);
        System.out.println("\n\n");


        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Clicccato 2 volte");
    /* JFrame frame=new JFrame("Configurazione");
     frame.setSize(400, 400);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setLocation(200, 300);
     JLabel titolo=new JLabel("Configurazione "+C.getName());
     JLabel rotazione=new JLabel("Rotazione");
     String [] val=new String [4];
     val[0]="0";
     val[1]="90";
     val[2]="180";
     val[3]="270";
     JComboBox scelta=new JComboBox(val);
     frame.add(titolo);
     frame.add(rotazione);
     frame.add(scelta);



//3. Create components and put them in the frame.
//...create emptyLabel...
//frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Configurazione"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

//4. Size the frame.
frame.pack();

//5. Show it.
frame.setVisible(true);*/

    }



Component C=e.getComponent();
C.getParent().repaint();
repaint();
System.out.println("Coordinate"+ C);

}
//mouseMoved
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
Component C=((Component)e.getSource());
java.util.Random r=new java.util.Random();
java.util.Random g=new java.util.Random();
java.util.Random b=new java.util.Random();
int cr=r.nextInt(255);int cg=g.nextInt(255);
int cb=b.nextInt(255);
Color col=new Color(cr,cg,cb);
//C.setBackground(col);


}
//mousePressed
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}

public class mouse_events{}

public static  void punti(){

    Inizio in=new Inizio();


    System.out.println("\n\n****************Controllo visibilità: ");
    System.out.println("Peso: "+pesoVisible);
    System.out.println("Tara: "+taraVisible);
    System.out.println("Logo1: "+logo1Visible);

    System.out.println("***********************************\n\n");


    if(logo1Visible){

    System.out.println("Parametri Logo1 "+logo1.getLocation());
    System.out.println("Parametri  X Logo1 "+logo1.getX());

    in.setLogo1X(logo1.getX());

   //System.out.println("Scrivo app: "+app);
    System.out.println("Parametri Y Logo1 "+logo1.getY());
    in.setLogo1Y(logo1.getY());
    }



    if(pesoVisible){

    System.out.println("Parametri Label "+label1.getLocation());
    System.out.println("Parametri  X Label "+label1.getX());

    in.setLabelX(label1.getX());

   //System.out.println("Scrivo app: "+app);
    System.out.println("Parametri Y Label "+label1.getY());
    in.setLabelY(label1.getY());
    }

    if(taraVisible){

    System.out.println("Parametri tara "+tara.getLocation());
    System.out.println("Parametri  X Tara "+tara.getX());
    in.setTaraX(tara.getX());

   //System.out.println("Scrivo app: "+app);
    System.out.println("Parametri Y Tara "+tara.getY());
    in.setTaraY(tara.getY());

    }

    System.out.println("Parametri Bar Code "+barcode.getLocation());
    System.out.println("Parametri  X Bar code "+barcode.getX()/10);
    in.setBarX(barcode.getX()/10);

   //System.out.println("Scrivo app: "+app);
    System.out.println("Parametri Y Bar Code "+barcode.getY()/10);
    in.setBarY(barcode.getY()/10);


//    System.out.println("Parametri nome "+nome.getLocation());
//    System.out.println("Parametri  X nome "+nome.getX()/10);
//    in.setNomeX(nome.getX()/10);

   //System.out.println("Scrivo app: "+app);
//    System.out.println("Parametri Y nome "+nome.getY()/10);
//    in.setNomeY(nome.getY()/10);

//    System.out.println("Parametri importo "+importo.getLocation());
//    System.out.println("Parametri  X importo "+importo.getX()/10);
//    in.setImportoX(importo.getX()/10);

   //System.out.println("Scrivo app: "+app);
//    System.out.println("Parametri Y importo "+importo.getY()/10);
//    in.setImportoY(importo.getY()/10);


 //   System.out.println("Parametri data "+data.getLocation());
 //   System.out.println("Parametri  X data"+data.getX()/10);
 //   in.setDataX(data.getX()/10);

  //aa=data.getX();

   //System.out.println("Scrivo app: "+app);
 //   System.out.println("Parametri Y data "+data.getY()/10);
 //   in.setDataY(data.getY()/10);

}



public void visibile(boolean vis){

  P.setVisible(vis);
 /*   
WindowEvent close = new WindowEvent(FRAME, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
FRAME.dispatchEvent(close);
    */

}


/*
private JComboBox getCombo(){
//final JSlider slider = new JSlider(-180, 180, angle);

    String[] val=new String [4];
    val[0]="0";
    val[1]="90";
    val[2]="180";
    val[3]="270";
 //final JComboBox combo1=new JComboBox(val);   

combo1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // angle = Integer.parseInt(combo1.getSelectedItem().toString());//.getValue();
                label1.getParent().repaint();
            }
        });
return combo1;
}*/

private JPanel getContent() {
label1.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 24));
label1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
panel.add(label1, new GridBagConstraints());
return panel;
}


 /*   
public static void main(String[] args)
{
prova t=new prova("MOUSE EVENT");
t.init();
}*/



public static void refresh(){


    //P.getParent().repaint();
    P.repaint();

    //add(label1);

    //repaint();
}



}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what you have tried, share your effort...?

Comment: With *share your effort* we do not mean to dump all your code here. Create an [sscce](http://sscce.org) instead

Comment: i need this: [link](http://jruntimedesigne.sourceforge.net).I Downloaded but the program not show the properties window... Can you Test it?

Comment: @oim There is way too much code to read in your example. Try to trim it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). What I can already tell you from here is that: 1. You have way too many `static` keyword. This is the sign of poor design and usually results in a non-OO code. You should almost have no `static`keywords, except for the `main` method and constants. 2. Follow Sun naming convention (variables starts with lower case letter) 3. Use meaningful variable names (don't use a, b, c, cb, label1, label2, etc...) 4. Write your program in english.

Comment: For Drag/Drop there is one wonderful layout by @camickr, [DRAGLAYOUT](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/). Have a look at this and do consider the wonderful advice as given by all fellow stackoverflow users :-)

Comment: @GagandeepBali Thank you, but i need to add other labels on runtime... the label's number is not know...

Answer (score 3):

Years ago I wrote a framework for this. Maybe it can serve you as a start (the library is Open Source):

Tutorial: http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/swing/customizer/index.html

Javadoc: http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/index.html

Homepage: http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.2</version>   
</dependency>
```

More info: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/07/news-from-software-smithy-version-02.html

Other solutions:

You could consider the NetBeans Platform and try to reuse either its Matisse component or the Visual Graph library.